# How to make simple join in relationship of Core Data Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have Core Data with relationship:

```
extension Rating {

    @NSManaged var date: NSString?
    @NSManaged var rating: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var ratenames: RateNames?

}

extension RateNames {

    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var rating: NSSet?

}
```

And I need to select all values from RateNames with all data from Rating linked to RateNames from a selected date.

For example RateNames data:

```
name=a; name=b;
```

For example RateNames data:

```
date=10-02-2016; rating=5; linked to a
date=10-02-2016; rating=3; linked to b
date=09-02-2016; rating=2; linked to a
date=08-02-2016; rating=3; linked to a
date=08-02-2016; rating=1; linked to b
```

For example I need result for `08-02-2016`
Result should be:

```
{(name:a, date:08-02-2016, rating=3), (name:b, date:08-02-2016, rating=1)}
```

result for `09-02-2016` date should be the following:

```
{(name:a, date:09-02-2016, rating=2), (name:b, date:nil, rating=nil)}
```

I also do need b in results because I need to see whether it is null or not.

I am trying to do something like:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "RateNames")
do {
    let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    for result in results {
let child = result. ..some var here.. as! Rating
```

But cannot get how to implement this

Comment: In your example expected results, a) why are the results grouped (with {}), and b) where does `(name:b, date:nil, rating=nil)` derive from?

Comment: @pbasdf a) it was written so just to make this example more visual b) it doesn't matter where from it derives, it also was written to make the example more visual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to get what you want by fetching the `Rating` objects, and using the relationship to get the `name` of the related `RateName` objects:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Rating")
do {
    let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Rating]
    for result in results {
        let name = result.ratenames.name
        let date = result.date
        let rating = result.rating
        print("name:\(name), date:\(date), rating:\(rating)")
    }
}
```

This will print results similar to your expected results, though it won't include the `(name:b, date:nil, rating=nil)`.

**Update**

If you want to limit the above to a given date, you can use a predicate for the fetch request:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"date == %@", chosenDate)
```

But since you want to include, `(name:b, date:nil, rating=nil)`, you will need to fetch ALL the `RatingName` objects.  The `rating` property of each object will include any and all `Ratings` to which it is related.  So I think you will then need to filter them to identify any for the correct date:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "RateNames")
do {
    let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format:"date == %@", chosenDate)
    for result in results {
        let filteredRatings = result.rating.filteredSetUsingPredicate(datePredicate)
        if filteredRatings.count > 0 {
            let rating = filteredRatings.anyObject()
            print("name:\(result.name), date:\(rating.date), rating:\(rating.rating)")
        } else {
            print("name:\(result.name), date:nil, rating:nil")
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes there can be only one `Rating` for each `RatingName` for a given date; if not you will have to iterate through the `filteredRatings` set.

Comment: Yes this worked for me previously but I had problem to make NSPredicate. Actually I need to select `result.ratenames.name`, `result.date`, `result.rating` for different dates. That is why I've tried to make `executeFetchRequest` from `RateNames` not from `Rating`. So the real result that I need is (name:a, date:[date], rating=5) - where [date] is the selected date. I will correct the question also.

Comment: Is there a more appropriate solution, something like sql join with where condition? It seems like this way I will do double filtering instead of just one. One on Core Data side and other one on the code side.

Comment: @Roberto Sorry, I can't think of a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to just setup `relationship` in `Datamodel` like i have created for following example

From your `code` i found that you didn't mentioned `One-to-Many Relationship` .

[image]
[image]
[image]

Then create again `sub class` of `NSManageObject`. `xCode` will create all needed `variables` for same.

Comment: I had already set all the relationship before I've asked the question and this did not solve the problem

Comment: Please check updated answer for regarding `oneToMany` relationship.

Comment: If you look on my extensions you can see that I already had one-to-many relationship set